# ReferenceError: utag is not defined only in private mode in Firefox 45.0.1

Tags: javascript, firefox, tealium

I have a code as following in my Magento application.

```
$tealium = $helper->getTealiumObject($store, $this);
$tealium->pageType("Cart");
echo $tealium->render("udo");
echo $helper->getDiagnosticTag($store);
$jsonUDO = $tealium->render("json");

echo <<<EOD
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    Checkout.prototype.gotoSection = function(section) {
        utag.data=$jsonUDO;
        utag.data["page_name"] = section;
        utag.view(utag.data);
        section = $('opc-'+section);
        section.addClassName('allow');
        this.accordion.openSection(section)
    }
});
</script>

EOD
```

I get *ReferenceError: utag is not defined*  error in browser console only when I am in the **private mode** and break execution, in normal mode it does not create any problem.

What has changed in Firefox 45.0.1 which is creating this issue?

Comment: You're not showing us how `utag` is defined ?

Comment: It is a code implemented by some other developer a long back and there is no where utag defined in the code.

Comment: Then firefox (and other browsers) *should* throw an error, as `utag` is not defined

Comment: @adeneo You are right but in normal mode it is not creating issue,but issue is in private mode.

Comment: I have no idea why that is, but the easy solution is to just write proper code, where the object `utag` is created before properties are assigned to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

In private browsing mode Firefox prevent the tacking. 
I have a a javascript file getting blocked by the Firefox http://tags.example.com/utag/some_name/client_name/prod/utag.js

Following is the message in the console

*The resource at "http://tags.example.com/utag/some_name/client_name/prod/utag.js" was blocked because tracking protection is enabled.*